# What is the minimum milliseconds value I can give to an erlang/elixir receive timeout?

Tags: loops, erlang, elixir

In erlang/elixir, a receive loop takes an optional after  timeout option. What is the minimum value it can be given as the  param?

Here's my code set to 1 millisecond.

```
def tick do
 receive do
   after
     001 ->
       IO.puts("200ms seconds elapsed")
       tick()
   end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

The smallest possible timeout value is **0 milliseconds**.  That is, you expect a message to already be in the message queue, and if it isn't, you don't want to wait for it.

I tried setting the timeout to a negative value.  I expected it to give a compilation error, but it didn't.  Instead, I got a runtime error:

```
** (ErlangError) Erlang error: :timeout_value
```

That makes sense in a way, since the timeout value doesn't have to be a constant: you can use the value of a variable as the timeout.

Answer (score 2):

As it is stated in the documentation for [`Kernel.SpecialForms.receive/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#receive/1),

> An optional after clause can be given in case the message was not received after the given timeout period, **specified in milliseconds** [...]

That said, the minimum value for the interval to time out would be *0ms* if one expects the message to be in the inbox *already* when it comes to `receive/1`.

Answer (score -3):

Found my answer, it goes wherever you want it, figures.

Comment: Please re-state the answer so it actually answers the original question.